# Need help for mouseout event in this code

Tags: jquery

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
   $(
   function () {
   $('li').mouseover(function () {
   var $this = $(this);
  $('#previewImage').animate({ opacity: 0.1 }, 0, function () {
  $(this).attr("src", 'img/' + $this.attr('id') + '.jpg').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
  });
  // mouseout should come here and hover image should come back to normal while mouseout

  });
  });
  </script>
```

Kinly help me, it should come here and hover image should come back to normal while mouseout event occur !!

Comment: What is actually happening instead? In general you will also want to wrap those event handlers in a `$(document).ready()` function to make sure the elemtsn exist when the event handler is added.

Comment: @ogc-nick - it's already wrapped in document ready, it just looks weird!

Comment: why creating new $this why you can just use $(this)?

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you had an HTML code in here as well. Here are some things to consider:

1. Wrap up your code with Document Ready function
2. Select the html attribute that you wish to animate on mouseover, and mouseout
3. And since one can pass functions to event handlers, and mouseover and mouseout are event handlers, I think it would be best if you pass functions to them.

Take a look at the snippet that I have below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $('previewImage').mouseover(function() {
            // pass the function here
        }).stop(true, true).mouseout(function() {
            // pass the function here
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Mosire,
  Thanks for your solution hint, In mouse out function i need to hide the previewImage Div Section.
.stop(true, true).mouseout(function() {
    $('#previewImage').hide();
}); // not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken your problem might be related to the this and $this you're using..
The second function, has a tottaly different this pointer in it..

I suggest you either pass it as a parameter

```
function (passThisPtr) {
$(this).attr("src", 'img/' + $this.attr('id') + '.jpg').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
});
```

or bind it to the parameter...

```
function () {
$(this).attr("src", 'img/' + $this.attr('id') + '.jpg').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
}.bind(passThisPtr));
```

Again, not knowing what's happening it's hard to know exactly but I presume this is the problem..